# Node Express Middleware outputting console.log() twice from one call?

Tags: node.js, express

just a quick question about some Node + Express middleware that is outputting 1 call to console.log twice in my node cmd prompt.  It just doesn't make sense and was wondering if someone could explain why this is occurring for me.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Outputs in my console twice?!
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Request Logged by Node+Express Server Middleware @ ' + Date());
    next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hey world.');
});

app.listen(1337);
```

Comment: Maybe this is getting buried by other questions, only 2 views :(

Comment: If you change from `app.use` to `app.get`, does it still log twice?

Comment: Hey it does, but I figured out that another request was being made to /favicon.ico by Chrome, thus producing 2 requests.  Makes sense now :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what was going on, Chrome was making an additional request to favicon.ico, thus the double outputs.  Makes sense.