# Console.log is called twice with Express Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I'm using express middleware to log all the requests made to the node server. Bit the log is being called twice, how do I avoid that?

The solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103921/node-express-middleware-outputting-console-log-twice-from-one-call) points to the possible reason, but how do I avoid it or bypass the fav.ico request.

Here is my code:

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Im being called', req.url);

  next();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude requests with URLs containing your favicon name or the '.ico' extension:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.url.includes('.ico'))
        console.log('Im being called', req.url)
    next()
})
```

Comment: Tried this, looks like the problem is not with the favicon. It is still being logged twice.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.url.includes('/favicon.ico')) {
    return next(); // specify return so the next console.log won't be executed
  }

  console.log("Im being called", req.url);  
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Log is called only once, but the code is not moving to the GET POST requests